# Двумерный массив.Поменять местами правую и левую половину матрицы

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Не могу нормально поменять правую половину матрицы с левой.Вообще код работает, но лишь частично, не высвечиваются верхние элементы рядом из 0 и 1 столба матрицы.Прошу помочь.
Код:

```
include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open("D:\\OP\\Індівідуалка\\Z4\\Matrix.txt");
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        cout << "Error";
    }
    else {
        cout << "The file is opened\n";
        int matrix[4][4];
        for (int i = 0;i < 4;i++) {
            for (int j = 0;j < 4;j++) {
                file >> matrix[i][j];
                cout << matrix[i][j] << "\t";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << "\n";
        for (int i = 0;i < 4;i++) {
            for (int j = 0;j < 4;j++) {
                        cout << matrix[i][j + 2] << "\t";
                    }
            cout << endl;
                }
            }

    }
```

Comment: Что-то тут не видно мест, где бы менялись эти половины. Зато видно место, где идет выход за пределы массива `matrix[i][j + 2]`

Comment: В где в коде обмен?

Comment: Я пытался поменять местами за счет перемещения по столбам

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну давайте подумаем... есть строка, в ней элементы 0123, нужно получить 2301, так? Т.е. обменять 0 и 2, и 1 и 3.

Как обменять две переменные, скажем, `a` и `b`?

```
int t = a; a = b; b = t;
```

Так? Ну, а теперь будем делать это в каждой строке:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    int t = matrix[i][0]; matrix[i][0] = matrix[i][2]; matrix[i][2] = t; 
    t = matrix[i][1]; matrix[i][1] = matrix[i][3]; matrix[i][3] = t;
}
```

Все, без проблем...

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: ну а если размеры большие ?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Значит, еще один цикл. Писать цикл для 2 элементов - перебор :)